# Provide the Proof for $\forall x\,\bigl ( P(x) \land Q(x)\bigr ) \leftrightarrow \forall x \,P(x) \land \forall x\, Q(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

Provide the Proof for $$\forall x\,\bigl ( P(x) \land Q(x)\bigr ) \leftrightarrow \forall x \,P(x) \land \forall x\, Q(x)$$

This is all I got so far:

Assume $\forall x \,\bigl( P(x) \land Q(x) \bigr)$ is true in some Universe $U$.
Then $x\, E \,P(x)$, $x\, E\, Q(x)$

I dont kno where to go from here :(.

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by $x\, E\, P(x)$?

Comment: x is an element of P(x)

Comment: there are many variations/ systems  of natural deduction , which book / system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

We prove it with *Natural Deduction*

*i)* For the "$\rightarrow$" part :

> (1) $\forall x ( P(x) \land Q(x) )$ --- assumed

(2) $P(a) \land Q(a)$ --- from (1) by $\forall$-elim

(3) $P(a)$ --- from (2) by $\land$-elim

(4) $\forall x P(x)$ --- from (3) by $\forall$-intro

(5) $Q(a)$ --- from (2) by $\land$-elim

(6) $\forall x Q(x)$ --- from (5) by $\forall$-intro

(7) $\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$ --- from (4) and (6) by $\land$-intro

> (8) $∀x ( P(x) \land Q(x) ) \rightarrow (\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x))$ --- from (1) and (7) by $\rightarrow$-intro .

*ii)* In the same way, we can prove the "$\leftarrow"$ part :

> $(\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)) \rightarrow ∀x ( P(x) \land Q(x) )$.

---

*Comment*

For a "semantic" argument, we can prove it in this way.

Consider an interpretation $\mathcal I$ with *domain* (or *universe*) $U$.

From the assumption $\forall x ( P(x) \land Q(x) )$ we have that, for each object $a \in U$, the "predicate" $P(x) \land Q(x)$ holds for it; i.e. :

> $P(a) \land Q(a)$ is true in the interpretation.

Thus, both $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$ are true.

But $a$ is an objcet whatever in the domain; thus also $\forall xP(x)$ and $\forall xQ(x)$ are true in the interpretation, and finally :

> $\forall xP(x) \land \forall xQ(x)$

is true in $\mathcal I$.

But $\mathcal I$ is an *interpretation* whatever; thus, the above argument shows that :

> $\forall x ( P(x) \land Q(x) ) \vDash \forall xP(x) \land \forall xQ(x)$

i.e. the RHS formula is true in every interpretation in which the LHS formula is.

This is the definition of *logical consequence*.

By properties of *logical consequence*, it follows that :

> > $\vDash \forall x ( P(x) \land Q(x) ) \rightarrow (\forall xP(x) \land \forall xQ(x))$.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.
But i dont understand what you mean by "From (1) by ∀-elim" or "from (2) by ∧-elim" and "from (3) by ∀-intro"

Could you please spell it out, and explain what you mean?

I do appreciate the answer. But i would like to learn from it as well =)

Comment: Im not very good at this.
Im trying to use a direct proof.
Like where you start out by saying, we assume ∀x(P(x)∧Q(x)) is True. Then, x is an element of P(x) and x is an element of Q(x).
Then, …. and your keep going down until you reach the end. Could you procide the proof in that manner please?

Comment: Ive read your expanded answer and im still having trouble putting it all together.=/  could you make it easier to understand. as if i had never heard of this topic before.

Comment: @user160406 - it is hard to "prove it" without a formal derivation or an "informal" argument... Intuitively, consider a box full of balls; if it is true that all ball are both "black and round" (which is $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$), then it follows that each single ball is "black and round". Then we have that each ball is "black" (i.e.$\forall xP(x)$) **and** each ball is "round" (i.e.$\forall xQ(x)$).

Comment: Is this correct: Assume ∀x(P(x)∧Q(x)) is true. then x ϵ p(x) and x ϵ Q(x). If x ϵ P(x) and P(x) belongs to ∀x and if x ϵ Q(x) and Q(x) belongs to ∀x . Then x ϵ ∀xP(x) and x ϵ ∀xQ(x). Therefore, ∀xP(x) ^ ∀xQ(x) is True.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I think im gunna call it a night.

Comment: @user160406 - but are you using a textbook or some lecture notes ? If so, we must find in it some "hints" about an "allowed" way of proving logical theorems ...

Comment: @user160406 - if I undersand well, you are "reading" the formulae as sets. When I say $P(x)$ holds for $a \in U$, you read it as $a \in P(x)$. Thus, saying that $\forall xP(x)$ is true simply means that the set of $a$ s.t. $P(a)$ is true is the *universe* $U$. Following this approach, we may say that from $\forall x(P(x) \land Q(x))$ follows that $U \subseteq (P(x) \land Q(x))$. But this amount to $U \subseteq (P(x) \cap Q(x))$ and this implies : $U \subseteq P(x)$ **and** $U \subseteq Q(x)$ which is $\forall xP(x) \land \forall xQ(x)$.